# Why is it neccessary to save created PDO object to next variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Why is it neccessary to save created PDO object to next variable? Why when i have

```
$db = new PDO;
$stmt = $db->Prepare("...");
```

I must save `$db` to `$stmt` to access some methods of `$db` and another methods I can call directly from `$db`. For example `$db->prepare(); $db->bindParam();` Is not working, but `$stmt=$db->prepare(); $stmt->bindParam();` is working. Why is that?

Comment: Actually, you don't have to save to another variable. Saving to another variable just helps especially when you intend on fetching results to be sent to your view file or used for other checks.

Comment: Not sure about what you're asking, are you asking why there is a `$db` variable ?

Comment: $db->prepare(); $db->bindParamater(); not working

Comment: $db->prepare(); $db->bindParam(); Is not working, but $stmt=$db->prepare(); $stmt->bindParam(); is working. Why is that?

Comment: Are you asking why you need to define a `new PDO` to a variable?

Comment: It works only when you follow the documentation about PDO and not trying to make up your own alternative methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because `$db` and `$stmt` are different kinds of objects. `$db` is a [PDO connection object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) representing a connection to the database, and `$stmt` is a [PDO Statement object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) representing a particular prepared query (or "statement").

When you write `$stmt = $db->prepare("...");` you don't "save $db to $stmt" (as you described it), that is not what is happening here. What is happening is that you are executing the method called [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) which is available in the connection object. This gets your SQL ready for execution and puts it into a Statement object, which it then returns to you. This is what ends up in the `$stmt` variable.

Then in order to bind parameters and execute the query, the methods to do that are part of the Statement object (and this is logical, because it's the statement you're executing - you don't execute a connection). `$db->bindParam();` doesn't work because there's no such method on the Connection object, and nor should there be - you bind the parameters to the statement directly.

Nothing complicated, strange or illogical is happening here - it's just a case of a method in one class returning an instance of another class, which has a different set of methods available (because it has a different purpose).

Read the documentation links I've provided and hopefully you'll start to understand the structure and how the different classes and methods relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

What that code is doing is preparing a SQL statement, effectively transforming it form a string value in PHP to a functional statement in your PDO (prepared data object, aka database connection). When you call the [prepare function on a PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), you pass in a SQL statement, and in return you get a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). The [PDO Statement is a feature of databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) that allows you to parameterise a statement, which in turn provides several benefits, such as:

1. Allowing to you reuse the statement without the RDMS having to recompile
2. Avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and therefore make your application more secure

Generally, once you have a Prepared Statement (your `$stmt` variable), you continue in your code with:

1. Bind parameter values, if it has parameters
2. Execute the statement
3. Fetch information about the executed statement, such as the row count, or the dataset that the statement has generated

---

In short, you aren't saving the value of `$db` to `$stmt`, but instead the PDO Statement generated by the `prepare()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean, why don't we just write `$db->prepare(...)` instead of `$stmt = $db->prepare` for example, i write this lines of code

```
$db = new PDO(....);
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Then next, we can write this

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
         // statements
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
if($db->query('SELECT * FROM table')->rowCount()) {
    while($data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // statements
    }
}
```

I hope you are understand, you don't have to store `$db` on `$stmt` everytime, it depends on how you write it.